# How to place the most repeated element as first position element in 1D array or vector in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

For example i want to convert

```
x = [45 25 65 70 60 70 45 70 15 70 25]
```

to

```
y = [70 45 25 65 60 45 15 25]
```

Here the most probable element is `70` so in new array `y` i want to keep `70` in first position, then other elements are to placed in new array.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
y = [mode(x) x(x ~= mode(x))]; %//remove most frequent element and add it to the front
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution.